# htaccess how to don't rewrite certain URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi fellow developers.

I am writing a hybrid website which contains static pages like index.php, page1.php... and a Nibbleblog that is installed in the top level directory at the same level where the static website is.

To enable SEO friendly URL's in the blog, I have added to htaccess a following Rewrite rules as recommended by Nibbleblog.

The RewriteBase `/eurotint/new-euroting/app/` is my current local development directory

```
RewriteBase /eurotint/new-euroting/app/
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&category=$1&number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&category=$1&number=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&tag=$1&number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&tag=$1&number=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&number=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=post&action=view&post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)/(.*)$ blog.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=page&action=view&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed/$ feed.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=page&action=$1 [L]
```

Now the problem:

This is working fine for enabling the SEO friendly URL's in the blog, however, if I have for example entered the blog post with address i.e.
**websiteAddress/eurotint/new-euroting/app/post/welcome-post/**

Then whenever I click on one of the static page addresses (index, page1, page2) while being on this or other blog page i.e. categories etc.

The rewrite rule redirects the address to something similar to: 
**websiteAddress/eurotint/new-euroting/app/post/welcome-post/index.php**

But I don't wan't the static addresses to be re-written i.e. clicking on home page button should take me to index page **websiteAddress/eurotint/new-euroting/app/index.php** and not **websiteAddress/eurotint/new-euroting/app/post/welcome-post/index.php**

I have tried some 301 redirects for the names of files that I don't wan't to redirect to blog page, but none of them worked and tbh. I am not expert in the Apache rewrite rules.

Also, all images urls of the static site, etc. are also being re-written while in the blog post/category, I would like to stop that also, and only re-write the urls that are related to the blog.

Any help on how to achieve that will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do with is with *file* and *directory* conditions - but because `RewriteCond` only affects the **next** rule you either need to add those conditions before each rule, or create a skip rule:

```
RewriteBase /eurotint/new-euroting/app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [S=10]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&category=$1&number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&category=$1&number=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&tag=$1&number=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&tag=$1&number=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)$ blog.php?controller=blog&action=view&number=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=post&action=view&post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)/(.*)$ blog.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=page&action=view&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^feed/$ feed.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ blog.php?controller=page&action=$1 [L]
```

The conditions (`RewriteCond`) state that if the requested filename *is* a file *or* a directory - [skip the next 10 rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s), so it *should* jump past all your rewrite rules.

This assumes that none of your defined rewrite matches point to actual existing files/directories (e.g. you don't really have a dir called *feed*).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have tried your suggestion, however I couldn't get it to work. I have ended up using the full web URL address in the navigation bar to solve this issue i.e. I have used https : // www. webaddress. com/ filreUrl, I know that it is not ideal but it solves this particular issue.